# Trouble with 2D camera controller in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have asked this question before and I never got a response back, my goal is to create a 2d camera controller in unity where it fill just always follow the players X axis, and on the y it will ignore the players Y until he reaches a specific height and then it will follow the player higher, here is my code:

```
public float baseCameraHeight = 5.0f; // default y-position of camera
public float heightThreshold = 20.0f; // minimum height for camera to follow vertically
public float cameraDistance = -10.0f;  // default z-position of camera
public gameobject player;

Vector3 playerPos = player.transform.position; line based on how the player 
Vector3 cameraPos = new Vector3(playerPos.x, baseCameraHeight, cameraDistance);
if (playerPos.y > heightThreshold)
{
    cameraPos.y += playerPos.y - heightThreshold;
}
Camera.main.transform.position = cameraPos;
```

This code works fine, except when the player reaches the height point, it will follow the player, but it keeps the player at the very top of the screen, Can I get some help?

Comment: Have you tried just lowering the heightTreshold? Seems like it should work like you want..

Comment: @FredrikWiderberg No, I need the camera to only follow the player on the y when he is up high

Comment: Yea. Thats what the code does, but since you want the camera centered on the player (i assume?) you would need a heightTreshold that starts following the player when he is above the center of the screen

Comment: @FredrikWiderberg Your not getting it, I need it to only occur when the play gets to the top of the screen and I need the camera to bring him back to the middle once he goes above the threshold

Comment: [mcve] [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/3404097)

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
public float heightThreshold = 20.0f; // minimum height for camera to follow vertically
public float cameraDistance = -10.0f;  // default z-position of camera
public GameObject player;
public Vector3 offset;

private float currentX;
private float currentY;

void Start()
{
    currentX = player.transform.position.x;
    currentY = player.transform.position.y;
}

void LateUpdate()
{
    currentX = player.transform.position.x;
    currentY = Mathf.Lerp(currentY, player.transform.y, 0.125f);

    Camera.main.transform.positoin = new Vector3(currentX, currentY, cameraDistance) + offset;

    if (player.transform.position.y > Camera.main.transform.position.y + heightThreshold)
        currentY = player.transform.position.y - heightThreshold;
    else if (player.transform.position.y < Camera.main.transform.position.y - heightThreshold)
        currentY = player.transform.position.y + heightThreshold;
}
```

Comment: How do I implement that into my code? there are multiple variables that are the same and multiple that are different but have the same name, and the player is a transform in your code but a gameobject in mine, can you give me a little more detail on how to implement it?

Comment: I mean that replace this code. I'm updating my code Now.

Comment: error CS1061: Type `UnityEngine.Vector3' does not contain a definition for `Y' and no extension method `Y' of type `UnityEngine.Vector3' could be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?

Comment: its `.y` not `.Y`

Comment: Sorry. Yeah it's `.y`

Comment: Ok, I got it working, it ends up not smoothly following the player up and it dosn't follow him down at all.

Comment: https://1drv.ms/v/s!Ai7u0bw9Rsr-ipxe6DGxUgd2ibz6qw sorry about the frame rate, I don't have the best recording software

Comment: @UltraGamer I think you want the camera to follow player only up. if you want to smooth following, you can use Lerp(). I'm updating my script.

Comment: Ok, It's much smoother now, it also follows my player down now, but when my player goes above the threshold the camera still doesn't slowly move to center the player in the middle of the screen.

Comment: also, I do notice that even though camera follows the player down, it dosn't go down quite as far as when it started leaving the ground just out of site, is there a solution it this?

Comment: Do you need to threshold? Remove all the content of LateUpdate() function. Then paste this code 
`Void LateUpdate() { Camera.main.transform.positoin = Vector3.Lerp(Camera.main.transform.position, new Vector3(player.transform.position.x, player.transform.position.y, cameraDistance), 0.125f); }` 
This code set player to center of camera every time. Also You can use if else statement to set boundary for camera follow your player.

Comment: OK, thank you for your help, I just have 2 smaller changes I would like to make though they don't have as big of a role, 1. is there a way to NOT lerp the camera to the players x axis. and 2. Can I create an "offset" that will modify the cameras y axis so the players not quite dead in the center?

Comment: oh, and can we make the camera not lerp to the player on the y axis until he passes the threshold?

Comment: Yes. You can use `Mathf.Lerp()` to lerp only Y-axis. I change my code to this. Also, you can set offset for the camera. if you want to use threshold, you should add if else statement again.

Comment: Sorry, how do I implement the Mathf.lerp()? and which//where do I put the else if statement?

Comment: I update the code and use Mathf.Lerp(), offset and threshold :)

Comment: ok, that stopped the camera from lerping on the x axis but the camera still ignores the threshold

Comment: Can you give me more information? How ignores the threshold?

Comment: it pretends as if there is no threshold and lerps the camera to the player no matter what (Sorry about the response time)

Comment: Please set offset to zero and see camera still ignores threshold or not :)

Comment: Ok, when I use the first bit of code you give me, it lerps only the the y axis (which is good) and it uses offset works but even when I set the offset to 0 it lerps to the player no matter what and there is a slight but noticeable amount of jitters once the player goes above the threshold.

 If I replace the update function with the new code you give me, it lerps to the player on the x and the y axis, there is some slight jitters when the player is moving, and it stops stops using the offset.

Is there a specific line of code you want me to use?

Answer (score 0):

When you remove the heightthreshhold from the player's position you are lowering the camera by the height thresh hold, thus making the character appear at the top of the screen. Set the camera's y position to exactly the player's y position when it's above that thresh hold to centre the player.
Replace the code inside the if statement with this:

`cameraPos.y = playerPos.y;`

This will snap horribly without a linear interpolation but should provide you with the expected results.

A smoother camera would use linear interpolation (Google it):

```
void FixedUpdate()
{
        cameraPos.x = playerPos.x
        if (playerPos.y > heightThreshold)
        {
        cameraPos.y = Mathf.Lerp(cameraPos.y, playerPos.y, Time.deltaTime * speed);
     //Speed should be changed by you to increase the speed the camera moves upwards.
        }
        else
        {
        cameraPos.y = MathF.Lerp(cameraPos.y, defaultCameraYValue, Time.deltaTime * speed);
//Default camera value is the Y value you want the camera to normally travel at
        }
    Camera.main.transform.position = cameraPos;
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178276/discussion-on-answer-by-will-anderson-trouble-with-2d-camera-controller-in-unity).